# Discovering Catch2 tests in Visual Studio when using CMake project

Tags: visual-studio, testing, cmake, try-catch

So far I've been developing my project using CLion on Linux and everything worked fine, but now I'm trying to setup my project on Windows to get familiar with the Visual Studio IDE, and I'm having trouble getting Visual Studio to discover my tests.

I'm using the CMake project directly in Visual Studio and things like building, running and etc. work fine, the problem beings when I try to run the individual tests using the `Run Test` option in the editor - the Test Explorer doesn't see them.

I've installed the `Catch2 Test Adapter` and added the required `.runsettings`, as described [here](https://github.com/JohnnyHendriks/TestAdapter_Catch2/blob/master/Docs/Walkthrough.md#trigger-test-discovery) but even with that the only things that I see in Tests output is

```
No tests found to run.
```

Has anyone tried a setup similar to this and can guide me on how to solve it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I got it working by generating a Visual Studio Solution and using it instead of the CMake project, my `.runsettings` look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <MaxCpuCount>4</MaxCpuCount>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory><!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <TestSessionTimeout>60000</TestSessionTimeout><!-- Milliseconds -->
  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

  <!-- Catch2 adapter -->
  <Catch2Adapter disabled="false">
    <FilenameFilter>test</FilenameFilter>
    <WorkingDirectoryRoot>Solution</WorkingDirectoryRoot>
  </Catch2Adapter>

</RunSettings>
```

Select it in `Test Explorer` > `Configure Run Settings` > `Select Solution wide runsettings File`

Comment: how is this a solution? Your original question asked how to get Test Explorer working with **CMake**.  It seems this "answer" is not a true answer, rather, it is a workaround by converting the cmake project to a Visual Studio Solution.